# how to draw the contour circle to find the residue poles in complex integrals?

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I have a complex integral to solve where we want to integrate $f(z) = {z\over(z-1)(z^2+1)}$ over the contour $C=16x^2+y^2=4$

My problem is that I don't know how to draw the contour circle and find $R$ to find out whether my poles are inside the region or not.

Comment: what is the function you're integrating?

Comment: z/((z-1)(z^2+1))  @CaptainChicky

Comment: 1) It's not a circle but an ellipse 2) test the sign of $16x^2+y^2-4$ : a pole $x+iy$ is inside the contour iff this sign is negative.

Comment: can you please explain more ?@JeanMarie

Comment: $16x^2+y^2=4 \iff  \frac{x^2}{(\color{red}{1/2})^2}+\frac{y^2}{\color{red}{2}^2}=1$ is an ellipse with semiaxes $1/2$ on $x$ axis, and $2$ on $y$ axis.

Comment: Hint: the points inside $16x^2+y^2=4$ are those with $16x^2+y^2<4$. Edit: I see @JeanMarie already made the same point.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we have $$f(z) = {z\over(z-1)(z^2+1)} = {z\over(z-1)(z-i)(z+i)}$$
This has poles at $z=1, \pm i$.
Your contour is an ellipse given by $\left(4x\right)^{2}+y^{2}=4$, which is a circle with its sides (left right) squashed by a scale factor of $4$, making it land at $1/2$.

From this, we can see that the only poles inside the contour are $z=\pm i$.
Here is why. Your three poles lie **on** the real and imaginary axis. Your ellipse is a circle squashed about the real axis. This means, the imaginary endpoints end at $\pm 2i$, and the real axis endpoints are $\pm \frac12$. This makes it obvious that the poles on the imaginary axis $\pm i$ lie inside the contour, and the real pole lies outside the contour since $\frac12 < 1$.

Now use the residue theorem

$$\text{your integral over your contour}= 2\pi i \operatorname{Res}(f(z), z=\pm i)$$

to calculate the value.

Comment: thank you for you explanation , but i still have a problem on how to know ehre my ellipse lands on , how can i find this out? @Captain Chicky

Comment: @maryjo see my edit

Comment: what if i had this function (z^2+2z+2)^2 , how can i find my poles ?@Captain Chicky

Comment: @maryjo that function has no denominator (it is a polynomial) and thus it is analytical on the entire complex plane. If we are integrating over the same contour then the integral is 0 since there *are no poles*.

Comment: sorry its 1/(z^2+2z+2)^2 @Captain Chicky

Comment: @maryjo still 0 because the poles are outside of the contour. find them by factoring the bottom (complete the square) and find roots of the denominator